# Python 3: how to scrape research results from a website using CSFR?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, csrf

I am trying to scrape the research outcome of a website listing French crowdlending Fintech: https://www.orias.fr/web/guest/search

Doing it manually, I select (IFP) in the radio button and then it provides me with 13 results page with 10 results per page. Each results has a hyperlink I would also like to get information from into the final table.

My main problem seems to come from CSRF, where in the result address, there is:
p_auth=8mxk0SsK
So I cannot simply loop through results pages by changing "p=2" to "p=13" in the link:
 https://www.orias.fr/search?p_auth=8mxk0SsK&p_p_id=intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_myaction=fullSearch

If I try to use a VPN manually, the wesite adress become "stable":
https://www.orias.fr/search?p_p_id=intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_d-16544-p=1&_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_implicitModel=true&_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_spring_render=searchResult

So I tried to use it in the python code:

```py
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    k = 1
    % test k from 1 to 13


    url = "http://www.orias.fr/search?p_p_id=intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_d-16544-p="  + str(k) + "&_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_implicitModel=true&_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_spring_render=searchResult"
    response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies) # 200 ment it went through    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered'})
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

    l = []
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [tr.text for tr in td]
        l.append(row)
```

Which doesn't work as it would in a web browser, it just provide a page as if no results had been requested. Would you know how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would alter the page param in the post requests during a loop. Do an initial request to find out number of pages

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, re, math
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.orias.fr/web/guest/search'
}

params = [['p_p_id', 'intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet'],
    ['p_p_lifecycle', '0'],
    ['p_p_state', 'normal'],
    ['p_p_mode', 'view'],
    ['p_p_col_id', 'column-1'],
    ['p_p_col_count', '1'],
    ['_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_d-16544-p', '1'],
    ['_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_implicitModel', 'true'],
    ['_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_spring_render', 'searchResult']]

data = {
  'searchString': '',
  'address': '',
  'zipCodeOrCity': '',
  '_coa': 'on',
  '_aga': 'on',
  '_ma': 'on',
  '_mia': 'on',
  '_euIAS': 'on',
  'mandatorDenomination': '',
  'wantsMandator': 'no',
  '_cobsp': 'on',
  '_mobspl': 'on',
  '_mobsp': 'on',
  '_miobsp': 'on',
  '_bankActivities': '1',
  '_euIOBSP': 'on',
  '_cif': 'on',
  '_alpsi': 'on',
  '_cip': 'on',
  'ifp': 'true',
  '_ifp': 'on',
  'submit': 'Search'
}

p = re.compile(r'(\d+)\s+intermediaries found')

with requests.Session() as s:
    r= requests.post('https://www.orias.fr/search', headers=headers, params= params, data=data)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') 
    num_results = int(p.findall(r.text)[0])
    results_per_page = 20
    num_pages = math.ceil(num_results/results_per_page)
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('.table')))[0]

    for i in range(2, num_pages + 1):
        params[6][1] = str(i)
        r= requests.post('https://www.orias.fr/search', headers=headers, params= params, data=data)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') 
        df_next = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('.table')))[0]
        df = pd.concat([df, df_next])

df.drop('Unnamed: 6', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

**Check:**

```
print(len(df['Siren Number'].unique()))
#245
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr, that is exactly what I was trying to do! Now the second step for me is to go on each company's extra page and get the date when it was granted the right to be an IFP, or the date when it was deleted (they unfortunately don't give us the date it was granted in the case it was deleted) and add it as a column of the dataframe and the list will be perfect ;) I will make use of the headers trick!

Answer (score 0):

So here is the full code, taking also into account that "Each results has a hyperlink I would also like to get information from into the final table". So for each firm, I update and headers and then scrape the date of Registration or Deletion. There might be a more elegant way to present the code...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, re, math
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.orias.fr/web/guest/search'
}

params = [['p_p_id', 'intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet'],
    ['p_p_lifecycle', '0'],
    ['p_p_state', 'normal'],
    ['p_p_mode', 'view'],
    ['p_p_col_id', 'column-1'],
    ['p_p_col_count', '1'],
    ['_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_d-16544-p', '1'],
    ['_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_implicitModel', 'true'],
    ['_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_spring_render', 'searchResult']]

data = {
  'searchString': '',
  'address': '',
  'zipCodeOrCity': '',
  '_coa': 'on',
  '_aga': 'on',
  '_ma': 'on',
  '_mia': 'on',
  '_euIAS': 'on',
  'mandatorDenomination': '',
  'wantsMandator': 'no',
  '_cobsp': 'on',
  '_mobspl': 'on',
  '_mobsp': 'on',
  '_miobsp': 'on',
  '_bankActivities': '1',
  '_euIOBSP': 'on',
  '_cif': 'on',
  '_alpsi': 'on',
  '_cip': 'on',
  'ifp': 'true',
  '_ifp': 'on',
  'submit': 'Search'
}

p = re.compile(r'(\d+)\s+intermediaries found')

def webdata(soup):
    parsed_table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
    dataweb = [[td.a['href'] if td.find('a') else 
             ''.join(td.stripped_strings)
             for td in row.find_all('td')]
            for row in parsed_table.find_all('tr')]
    dfweb = pd.DataFrame(dataweb[1:], columns=['SIREN','ID','website','category','zipcode','city','website2'])
    dfweb = dfweb.loc[:,['ID','website']]
    dfweb.ID = dfweb.ID.astype(int)
    return dfweb

with requests.Session() as s:
    r= requests.post('https://www.orias.fr/search', headers=headers, params= params, data=data)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') 
    num_results = int(p.findall(r.text)[0])
    results_per_page = 20
    num_pages = math.ceil(num_results/results_per_page)
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('.table')))[0]
    dfweb = webdata(soup)
    df = pd.merge(df,dfweb, on='ID')

    for i in range(2, num_pages + 1):
        params[6][1] = str(i)
        r= requests.post('https://www.orias.fr/search', headers=headers, params= params, data=data)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') 
        df_next = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('.table')))[0]
        dfweb = webdata(soup)
        df_next  = pd.merge(df_next ,dfweb, on='ID')
        df = pd.concat([df, df_next])

df.drop('Unnamed: 6', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True) 

# list the ORIAS identity number given to frims
# get le last 6 character of the link, but last is a space
df['oriasID'] = df.website.apply(lambda x: x[-7:][:6])
# remove = sign, non digit
df['oriasID'] = df.oriasID.apply(lambda y: ''.join(i for i in y if i.isdigit()))


# new parameters
def paramsub(IDi):
    return [['p_p_id', 'intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet'],
    ['p_p_lifecycle', '1'],
    ['p_p_state', 'normal'],
    ['p_p_mode', 'view'],
    ['p_p_col_id', 'column-1'],
    ['p_p_col_count', '1'],
    ['_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_myaction', 'viewDetails'],
    ['_intermediaryDetailedSearch_WAR_oriasportlet_partyId', IDi]]


df['date in'] = False
df['date out'] = False
with requests.Session() as s:
    for i in df.index:
        IDi = df.loc[i,'oriasID']
        r= requests.post('https://www.orias.fr/search', headers=headers, params= paramsub(IDi), data=data)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') 
        # keep data inside blocint3 is "(IFP)" is in the text
        for rowi in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'blocint3'}):
            if 'IFP' in rowi.text:
                if 'Deleted' in rowi.text:
                    # identify date
                    df.loc[i,'date out'] = re.search(r'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}', rowi.text).group()
                elif 'Registered' in rowi.text:
                    df.loc[i,'date in'] = re.search(r'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}', rowi.text).group()

# dates to date format
df['date in'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date in'], format="%d-%m-%Y", errors='coerce')
df['date out'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date out'], format="%d-%m-%Y", errors='coerce')

# sort by dates
df = df.sort_values(by='date out',ascending=True)
df = df.sort_values(by='date in',ascending=True)

df = df.reset_index(drop=True) 
# export
df.to_csv('20190817_ORIAS_in_out.csv')
```